# How to create columns in a view from calculations of columns in a table?

Tags: mysql

I have a table with 3 columns:
ID, AgeRecievedWeeks, DateReceived

I would to have a query that calculated the DateBorn, AgeDays, and AgeMonth but does not add those columns to the original table.

Can I create a view that accomplishes this?

I tried:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW `testOutput` AS 
SELECT ID,
    AgeReceivedWeeks,
    DateBorn AS DATE_SUB(DateReceived, INTERVAL AgeReceivedWeeks WEEK),
    AgeDays AS DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), DateBorn),
    AgeMonths AS TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY, DateBorn, CURDATE()) / 30
    FROM kdys_animals.`Test`;
```

but this says I have and error in syntax near 'DATE_SUB(DateReceived, INTERVAL AgeReceivedWeeks WEEK),

Comment: Be aware that queries against views in MySQL cannot access underlying indexes, rendering their utility questionable. For further help, please see: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: oh, that is good to know. Thanks for the heads up. Probably better to just add the new columns to the original table with UPDATE, then, and make sure that users can't add entries into the calculated fields.

Answer (score 0):

Alias is given after the column name or expression not before. `DateBorn` is calculated in same row, don't rely whether it would be available for next column.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW `testOutput` AS 
SELECT ID,
    AgeReceivedWeeks,
    DATE_SUB(DateReceived, INTERVAL AgeReceivedWeeks WEEK) AS DateBorn,
    DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), DATE_SUB(DateReceived, INTERVAL AgeReceivedWeeks WEEK)) As AgeDays,
    TIMESTAMPDIFF(MONTH, DATE_SUB(DateReceived, INTERVAL AgeReceivedWeeks WEEK), CURDATE()) AS AgeMonths
FROM kdys_animals.`Test`;
```

Comment: I ran that and got the error "Unknown column 'DateBorn' in 'field list'".  But seems like the VIEW won't be very usful in the long run anyway, as explained by @strawberry above.  Thanks.